# How to use a value changed by useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

So I have my code like this:

```
var problems = ['a','b','c'];
  var allProblemStatus;
  var selectProblemStatus = "";

  useEffect(() => {
    let getProblemStatus = async() => {
      let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/problem-status/');
      allProblemStatus = await response.json();
      selectProblemStatus = allProblemStatus['problem_status'];
    }
    getProblemStatus();
  }, []);

return (
    <div>
    {problems.map((problem, index) => (
        <Grid item xs={200} md={100} lg={5}>
          <Problem key={index} problem={problem} a={selectProblemStatus} />
        </Grid>
      
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

`selectProblemStatus` is being changed in useEffect but how do I actually use it to pass it to the `Problem` component as a prop, also is there a way to console.log the changed `selectProblemStatus`

Comment: You use initialise those variables as state, and let the code in `useEffect` update those states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is clear that you are unfamiliar with `useState` hook in react.
your approach should be look like this:

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const [problems, setProblems] = useState([])
  
  const getProblemStatus = async () => { ... }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProblemStatus()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
    {problems.map((problem, index) => (
        <Grid key={index} item xs={200} md={100} lg={5}>
          <Problem problem={problem} a={selectProblemStatus} />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **useState()**  hook for your variables, and then in **useEffect** update them. Here is link how to use useState https://uk.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html